# can't seem to get this ajax code to work? Won't display "dynamically"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a live search bar where if the user types in "M" only results that have an M are shown and so on, i've made each result into a link so when the user clicks it, it'll load to a different page.

Now, I can make it load to another page, however I'm trying to do it on the same page but it just wont work.

The search code is simply a form that takes text, then im using the xmlhttp method to make it live.

Now, displaying it is as follows: (I have given it a class to use in the ajax)

```
echo "<a href = 'display.php' class='display'>" . $row['carName'] . "</a>";
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".display").each(function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.on("click",function(){
            $("#displayDiv").empty();
            $.post("display.php",function(data) {
                $("#displayDiv").append(data);
```

Any help? Currently, clicking it just loads test.php on which I have some text to see its working. I'm trying to get it to load dynamically on the right.

Thanks.

EDIT: it loads test.php which is:

```
<html>
    <body>    
        <div id="displayDiv">    
            <h2> Test </h2>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT2: div id which is in the same page as script:

```
<html>

<div id="displayDiv" style="width: 40%; float:right">


</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an element in your HTML with the `id` value `"displayDiv"`?

Comment: yep, in my html i've given the div id=displayDiv

Comment: Your edit changes things markedly. You code looks for a `#displayDiv` element **already on the page** and tries to append the markup from `test.php` to it. But your edit shows us that the `#displayDiv` element *isn't* on the page, it's in the `test.php` markup. So where on the page do you want the markup to go? And how much of that markup do you want? Just the bit inside `#displayDiv`? `#displayDiv` and the markup inside it?

Comment: Ok, i'm a tad lost (sorry new to this!). I'm trying to just get it to display on the right hand side of the page (or middle) anywhere next to the search results...

Comment: @ user: So what are the answers to the questions at the end of the comment above?

Comment: You need to have a container element to inject the ajax response into. We thought that was the #displayDiv but now it seems that is on the target page. Is there an element on the main page where you want to show the content?

Comment: Right, think I understand what you're saying. On my live search page, I have added a small html (just above the script), check edit please.

Comment: If you're not posting any parameters to display.php, couldn't you use `$('#displayDiv').load('display.php #displayDiv');` to load the displayDiv of the target page into the displayDiv of the main page?

Comment: Not posting any parameters currently to display.php (as im just trying to get it to work) but eventually the id's of my cartable will be posted in order to find specific cars

Comment: Ah ok, stick with post then.

Answer (score 3):

It's just following the link when you click on it. To stop this you need to change the event handler to:

```
btn.on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code
});
```

Comment: Then I think we need more details of the problem. You say it loads test.php but we don't know what that is or where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".display").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#displayDiv").empty();
        $.post("display.php", function(data) {
                $("#displayDiv").append(data);
            }
        );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```